# Do abandoned sewers and underground tunnels really exist like portrayed in movies?

Tags: underground, infrastructure, criminal-underworld

In movies there are man-size tunnels where criminals or main characters are hiding or living. Do such tunnels exist in real life and, if so, why are they not controlled. Why is there still power on?

Comment: *All* tunnels are underground... *Power* is usually not on, unless the enterprising criminals made an illegal connection (not hard to do). But, yes, many cities have an awful lot of disused tunnels under them. from the narrowgauge [coal delivery tunnels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Tunnel_Company) of Chicago to the abandoned underground (metro) tunnels and stations in Paris, Moscow, New York and so on. Not counting many abandoned freeways and railroads around the world, complete with tunnels and sometimes spectacular viaducts. Please do at least a little bit of research.

Comment: Why are *abandoned* tunnels not controlled? Maybe it's because they're *abandoned*?

Comment: Of course they exist. Have you done any research at all on this? Search for these queries: "urbex", "draining", "mole people", "utility tunnel", "cartel tunnel", "Gaza Strip tunnel", "Paris catacombs", "scuba diving missile silo".

Comment: You are expected to show some attempt to answer a question on your own before asking, You are also expected to stick to one question at a time.

Comment: Hi Michael --- please check out the [help] and [tour] so can get a better idea how things work here, why your question is being closed, why you're not being treated like a delicate snowflake, etc.

Answer (score 5):

As others pointed out, lots of such places exist. Cities usually try to keep them locked, mostly so kids don't get lost in there. Where they fail, it's usually hobos who occupy them or adventurers who explore them - loads of videos for that.

Unlike the movies, criminals are usually not interested in them - difficult to get friends or employees there to protect your stashes or produce your goods, difficult to escape if the police comes for you, easy to have 'accidents' happen to you (Methane, CO, crumbling ceilings...) and so on. Also, a criminal who makes good money can have a villa with lots of bunnies, a big swimming pool and a place for a yacht instead - so why go underground?

The same with Batman's batcave, evil scientists' hide-outs in James Bond movies and so on. In reality very unrealistic, but makes for good movie scenes.

However, governments, sometimes with evil intent, do that regularly - mountain fortresses (Gibraltar and many others), mountain airbases (Germany in Czechia), subterranean production facilities (everyone) and so on. They have lots of money to spare and have less difficulty motivating people to work in such a place.

Comment: Yes. Germany in particular during WW2 built lots of tunnels. The purpose of most was to protect the manufacture of aircraft, munitions etc. from bombing by the Allies. https://www.urbanghostsmedia.com/2017/03/abandoned-underground-factories-ww2/  In London there are many abandoned Underground stations - Photos here - http://www.abandonedstations.org.uk/